# How to turn non-printable characters into their hex values in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, hex, ascii

I'm trying to make a function that takes an array of characters as an input, and outputs printable characters normally, and non-printable characters in hexadecimal (by turning these character into decimal using Extended ASCII, then turning that decimal number into hex).
For example:

```
"This morning is ßright"
```

should turn into:

```
"This morning is E1right"
```

since **ß** in Extended ASCII is **225**, and that in hexadecimal is **E1**.

Here is what I attempted:

```
void myfunction(char *str)
{
    int size=0;
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != NULL; i++) size++; //to identify how many characters are in the string
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (isprint(str[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", str[i]); //printing printable characters
        }
        else
        {
            if (str[i] == NULL) break; //to stop when reaching the end of the string
            printf("%02x", str[i]);  //This is where I'm having an issue     
        }
    } 
}
```

This function outputs this:

```
"This morning is ffffffc3ffffff9fright"
```

how can I turn the non-printable characters into their hex value? and what is causing this function to behave in this way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are making some assumption that are wrong. `ß` does not exist in ASCII.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to cast to `unsigned char` before passing it to `printf`.

Comment: Characters are typically signed twos-complement 8-bit values. When passed to printf a `char` is sign extended to `int`. All those `f` characters are the sign bit being copied to convert the 8-bit number to a 32-bit number. To fix it, use a cast: `printf("%02x", (unsigned char)str[i]);`

Comment: @Gerhardh How can I do that?

Comment: @TedLyngmo it exists in Extended ASCII, check this: https://theasciicode.com.ar/

Comment: @Chainsburg I was talking about ASCII. Extended ASCII is not it. If you talk about one of the extensions, please make it clear which one you are talking about.

Comment: `it exists in Extended ASCII` Well, then, do you think your PC is using extended ASCII? If you want to output the hexadecimal encoding of extended ASCII of characters, you have to first convert them from the input encoding (most probably unicode UTF-8) and output the associated hex value from extended ASCII.

Comment: “Extended ASCII” is too vague in general. Use a codepage name directly to refer to expected charset definition.

Comment: btw: the `c3` and `9f` are the UTF-8 encoding of `ß`. So you aren't using extended ASCII.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Appologies! I changed it in the post to Extended ASCII.

Comment: No need to appologize. You could use [`iconv`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) to make it into whatever you need and then print the unicode code points. I predict that will work for quite a long time, unlike ASCII.

Comment: _Side note:_ The `if (str[i] == NULL) break;` is superfluous--remove it. It is already handled by `str[i] != 0;` in the `for` loop

Comment: To get rid of the upper bits you can do as Chris Dodd shows or you can use unsigned type: `printf("%02x", (unsigned char)str[i]);`. Unsigned type are not sign extended when converted to `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing a couple of issues here.  The first is that the `char` type on your machine (as on most) is signed, so when you have a char that is not ascii, it shows up as a negative number.  This then sign extends to your int size before you print it as an unsigned hex value, so you get those ffffff strings you see.

If you mask it to 8 bits, you'll see the hex values more clearly.  Use

```
printf("%02X", str[i] & 0xff);  // X to use upper-case hex chars for clarity
```

and you'll get the output

```
This morning is C39Fright
```

Now you see the second problem, which is that ß is *not* an ascii character.  It is unicode character #00DF, however, and when it is encoded in UTF-8 it shows up as the two-byte sequence C3 9F.

Answer (score 1):

You have plenty of issues with your code.

`for (int i = 0; str[i] != NULL; i++) size++;` `NULL` is a pointer `str[i]` is `char`. You simply want to compare with `zero` which is a ***null character***. *null character* is not the same as NULL pointer!!!

Same here: `if (str[i] == NULL) break;`

`printf("%02x", str[i]);` you use wron format to print `char` value as number. You should use `hh` size modifier. See how it works in the attached code.

Use the correct type for indexes or sizes - `size_t` instead of `int`

Your code is overcomplicated.

```
void myfunction(const char *str)
{
    while(*str)
    {
        if (isprint(*str))
        {
            printf("%c", *str); //printing printable characters
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%02hhX", *str);  //This is where I'm having an issue     
        }
        str++;
    } 
}

int main(void)
{
    char *str = "This morning is \xE1right";

    myfunction(str);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6jKWdr3rM